# Having a hard time reading in a text file into java(Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having a hard time trying to read in a text file into java. Basically, when the program tells me to "Enter file name" I do it. However it comes back as

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Students.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

And I don't know why it's doing that. I have spent hours searching the internet for help and nada. I added a screenshot to show how I have my files. I don't know if it helps or not.

[image: Here is a screen shot of how I have my files. I don't know if it helps or not.]

Well I've tried adding `import java.FileNotFoundException` and nothing.

So this is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Match 
{


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
        String filename = input.next();


        Student[] student = new Student[100];

        for (int i=0; i < 100; i++)
            student[i]= new Student();

        try 
        {
            Scanner kbd = new Scanner (new FileReader(filename));
            int count = 0;

            while (kbd.hasNextLine())
            {
                Scanner line = new Scanner(kbd.nextLine());
                line.useDelimiter("[\t-]");

                student[count].setname(line.next());
                student[count].setgender(line.next().charAt(0)); 
                student[count].getbirthDay().setmonth(line.nextInt()); 
                student[count].getbirthDay().setday(line.nextInt());
                student[count].getbirthDay().setyear(line.nextInt());
                student[count].getpref().setquietTime(line.nextInt());
                student[count].getpref().setmusic(line.nextInt());
                student[count].getpref().setreading(line.nextInt());
                student[count].getpref().setchatting(line.nextInt());
                count++;
            }

            for(int i=0; i< count; i++)
            {
                Student s1 = student[i];
                Student bestMatch=null;
                int bestScore=0;
                int currentScore;

                if (s1.getmatch())
                    continue;


                for (int j= i+1; j<100; j++)
                {
                    Student s2 = student[j];
                    currentScore=s1.compare(s2);

                    if (!s2.getmatch() && (currentScore>0) && (bestMatch == null || currentScore > bestScore))
                    {
                        bestMatch = s2;
                        bestScore=s1.compare(bestMatch);
                    }

                }

                if (bestMatch != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(s1.getname() + " matches with " + bestMatch.getname() + " with the score " + bestScore);
                    s1.setmatch(true);
                    bestMatch.setmatch(true);
                }
                else
                    System.out.println(s1.getname() + " has no matches.");
            }

        }

        catch (NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try moving the file to the project root (looks like it's inside `src` atm).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was having a hard time formatting that part. lol

Comment: Just select the whole code and click on the `{}` icon next time ;)

Comment: Well when I move the file to {src} , it puts it inside the default package. I just mad a different folder to see if that helps but nothing.

Comment: Looks like the file is not in the same directory as tha program working directory. Try to enter the fullt path.

Comment: Lol thanks. For the coding. I don't always ask for help but when I do it's here. always helpful

Comment: @Jens so entering Students.txt is not enough?

Comment: @Oyukyfairy If the file is not in the actual working dir the answer is NO.

Comment: @Jens I'm sorry I am not Java savvy. What is the directory again? (I have to take a programming class for my major)

Comment: @Oyukyfairy The working dir is the directory where you start your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are running your program, lets say in

```
 /home/myaccount/workspace/project2
```

directory, and you re looking for a file sample.txt, java expects that you are looking it in relative location, so it's

```
/home/myaccount/workspace/project2/sample.txt
```

If you want to give a particular file in your suystem you need to give it a full path, starting by your root.

Solution to your problem:
move your file to directory, where your java class is, thats it:)

Comment: Damn, forgot you are using windows, I game my example in inux env, but the idea is the same:)

Comment: Thank you! You guys are my heros! Screw superman I got you guys

Answer (score 0):

Just put Students.txt within the project and not under your package. So location of your file would be:

```
.......\project2\Students.txt
```

Comment: I want to check your green mark too but I can't :( I love you guys

Comment: that's ok mate. Enjoy your day :).